# Webpack - File Loader - Parent Directory + Different Served Path

Tags: css, fonts, webpack, assets, webpack-file-loader

Good evening,

Given an image/font file located at `assets/images/myimg.png` (or `assets/fonts/myfont.woff`).....

I want webpack's `file-loader` to create a hashed version in a different directory (`../priv/static/fonts/myfont.woff`)...

But I don't want that name to be part of the "served asset path for the file".

If I use `file-loader` with a `name` option that looks like this: `"../priv/static/fonts/[name]-[hash].[ext]"`, the file ends up in the right place in my file system.

But when referenced from CSS, the full path that the browser is looking for is `http://mysite.dev/priv/static/fonts/myfile-fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff`. My web server serves static files from `priv/static`, so I want the requested path to just look like `http://mysite.dev/fonts/myfile-fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff`.

I am committing `assets/images` and `assets/fonts` to source control, so I don't want all of the hashed files to end up in that directory.

Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just assign a different path for your build that's going to your server, like `/fonts/[name]-[hash].[ext]`?

Comment: @Doodlebot Do you mean configure my webserver to serve from a different directory? I feel like that shouldn't be required... !

Comment: I probably didn't fully understand the problem on the first read through. So is main issue is that server request path is `http://mysite.dev/fonts/file.woff`, but your css is still looking for `http://mysite.dev/priv/static/fonts/file.woff` and you want webpack to make the css use the server's path?

Comment: @Doodlebot No problemo. The "public" folder my web framework (elixir/phoenix) provides is in the `priv/static` directory.  I need to get built files into that directory - e.g. I need to get the hashed font file to `priv/static/fonts/file-[HASH].woff`. However when other files reference this asset, it needs to be relative to the public dir - i.e. other references should be to `/fonts/file-[HASH].woff`.  I can get the file in the right place using the `name` option in `file-loader`, but I can't strip the `/priv/static` prefix from the path when other resources request this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the file-loader documentation, the publicPath parameter seems to be what you need, though they don't go into a lot of detail.
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#filename-templates

Here's a discussion on Github with a similar issue.
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/32#issuecomment-250622904

I think you should be able to do something like this:

`../priv/static/fonts/[name]-[hash].[ext]&publicPath=/fonts/`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found this as well - public path didn't really work out for me standalone. It turns out that having relative paths in `output.path` doesn't really play well with anything. I adjusted that config (and included publicPath), and it appears that `file-loader` will behave as expected now. Will mark this as accepted, as others who stumble here probably won't have started with a relative path in their `output.path`.